# JSF 2 convertNumber permille

Tags: jsf, number-formatting

We have a #{object.amount} equal to 0.003 and we would like to display it as 3‰ (With the permille operator)

We also would like to convert the value of an inputText to permille. (e.g: a user input of 3 will store 0.003)

The f:convertNumber allow us to convert to the type % but not ‰ :

```
<h:outputText value="#{object.amount}" >
    <f:convertNumber type="percent" />
</h:outputText>
```

How can we display a value permille in an outputText and convert a value to a permille in an inputText ?

Comment: By creating a custom converter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Kukeltje suggested, you can implement a custom converter, for example:

```
@FacesConverter("permilleConverter")
public class PermilleConverter implements Converter {

  private static final String PERMILLE_SYMBOL = "‰";
  private static final int PERMILLE_FACTOR = 1000;

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return getDoubleValue(value) / PERMILLE_FACTOR;
  }

  private Double getDoubleValue(String value) {
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
    Double doubleValue;
    try {
      Number number = nf.parse(value);
      doubleValue = number.doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      throw new ConverterException("no valid format");
    }
    return doubleValue;
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }
    double amount = (double) value;
    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
    return nf.format(amount * PERMILLE_FACTOR) + PERMILLE_SYMBOL;
  }

}
```

And use it like this:

```
<h:form>
    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.amount}">
        <f:converter converterId="permilleConverter" />
    </h:outputText>

    <h:inputText value="#{userBean.amount}">
        <f:converter converterId="permilleConverter" />
    </h:inputText>

    <h:commandButton value="test">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Comment: I did something similar after Kukeltje comment but this detailed response will be great for future similar inquiries. Thx !